# Efficient way to convert all data frame columns in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do type cast of all data frame columns based on an input as shown below, how can I do this with a single command that converts all data frame columns? The following code works fine, but I need a generic command that works for any data frame. Thanks in advance for your kind suggestions.

```
    for (colIndex <- 0 to tmpDF.columns.length - 1) {

      val columns = df.columns
      newdf = df.withColumn(columns(0), df(columns(0)).cast(dataType(0)))
        .withColumn(columns(1), df(columns(1)).cast(dataType(1)))
        .withColumn(columns(2), df(columns(2)).cast(dataType(2)))
        .withColumn(columns(3), df(columns(3)).cast(dataType(3)))
        .withColumn(columns(4), df(columns(4)).cast(dataType(4)))

   //  newdf = df.withColumn(columns(colIndex), df(columns(colIndex)).cast(dataType(colIndex))) --> This didn't work, only last column was updated

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It only updates the last column because you always append to column to `df`, you should keep appending to `newDF` This should work:

```
var newDF = df
val columns = df.columns
for (colIndex <- tmpDF.columns.indices) {
    newDF = newDF.withColumn(columns(colIndex), df(columns(colIndex)).cast(dataType(colIndex))) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are doing many withColumn - there are ok, but each withColumn adds Projection to query plan. It's better to do one big select:

```
val columns = df.columns
val columnsNew = new Array[Column]
for (colIndex <- tmpDF.columns.indices) {
    columnsNew(colIndex) = columns(colIndex), df(columns(colIndex)).cast(dataType(colIndex))) 
}
var newDF = df.select(columnsNew :_*)
```

You should have only one projection, so it can be faster on very large dataset - CodeGen deal better with less amount of projections in query plan, that's why it's better to do single select with multiple columns :)

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I've used part of your code and I up voted your answer as "thank you" :) Hope it's ok for you

Comment: Nice option! It seems that the code can get more complicated if we want to process only a subset of the columns without removing the others or changing the order, in which case I think it might be worth sticking to `withColumn`, am I wrong?

Comment: @DanieldePaula Yes, withColumn is very good for dealing with subset of columns or just adding or changing manually few columns :) Congrats for the Spark Top 20! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion, using a more "functional way", is with `foldLeft`. In this case, your "dataType" variable can be a `Map[String, DataType]` (or `Map[String, String]`) mapping each column name to the new type you want to give :

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq((1, "1"), (2, "2")).toDF("col1", "col2")

val dataType: Map[String, DataType] = Map(
  "col1" -> StringType,
  "col2" -> IntegerType
)

val result = df.columns.foldLeft(df) { 
  (newDF, colName) => newDF.withColumn(colName, newDF(colName).cast(dataType(colName)))
}

result.show
```

Note that no mutable vars were needed, which in Scala should often be our goal.

If you want to keep using the indexes instead of the column names, you can adapt the code above accordingly:

```scala
val dataType = List(StringType, IntegerType)
val cols = df.columns
val result = cols.indices.foldLeft(df) { 
  (newDF, i) => newDF.withColumn(cols(i), newDF(cols(i)).cast(dataType(i)))
}
```

In both cases, the output is:

```scala
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: int, col2: string]
result: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: int]

+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|   1|
|   2|   2|
+----+----+
```

[Here](https://coderwall.com/p/4l73-a/scala-fold-foldleft-and-foldright) you can find some info about `foldLeft`.